# Molecular add-on Error Message: ‘cmolcore’ is not defined

Tags: scripting, add-on, error

I've installed the molecular script addon in several version of Blender (2.78/2.71) but when I use the 'bake' option I get an Error Message:

```
Traceback
File “C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.71\scripts\addons\molecular\_init_.py”,line 600, in execute mol_report = cmolcore.init(mol_exportdata)
NameError: name ‘cmolcore’ is not defined
Location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Everything works fine until baking.

Can anyone help me? I'm sure I've installed the appropriate version of the addon. I have seen other questions about the traceback error, but my problem still isn't resolved. The molecular script works perfectly at the computer of my supervisor.
I've also a 'command prompt' file (see image). I guess something is wrong in .py(d)?

[image: Command prompt file]

I've changed the name of the folder 'molecular' to 'add_mesh_siding_utils'

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there's an error with an addon report it to the addon author

Comment: **v1.03 work with python 3.5 and need Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015** Check if you have installed Microsoft Visual C++ package.